# Check object memory allocation of String

Tags: java, string

Suppose I've created a String object like

```
String st = new String("newOBject");
```

and another by

```
String str = "secondObject";
```

Now my question is how I will confirm whether the object created by String literal is created inside String pool and with object created with new operator is create inside Heap memory. Is there any method which can go inside the memory and can tell us it location

Comment: Java? To avoid an XY problem, can you explain why you'd want to know?

Comment: agree @M.leRutte And knowledge from one VM / configuration may be useless on the other

Comment: The copy constructor `String(String)` is an artifact for the early days of java, paused from C++ and utterly senseless, as Strings are immutable objects. For memory locations and memory usage others will shed their view. In **java 9** there will be the configurable feature that internal representation no longer solely use the 2-byte chars but also single byte encodings like ISO-8859-1. With that reducing the memory footprint of average applications.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly looking into the memory for Strings you can do the following:

```
boolean isStringInPool(String stringToCheck){
    String test = new String(stringToCheck);
    test = test.intern();
    return stringToCheck == test;
}
```

That is creating a String with the same value on the heap, interning it (which forces it to be in the pool), and comparing the reference (which returns true only if both are in the pool)